# URL string parameters passed to MVC controller action arrive as null

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, string, controller, null

Have Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyAction(int iMode, string strSearch)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In my view I have a div with id=center

I execute the following code in javascript

```
url = "/MyController/MyAction?iMode=7&amp;strSearch=as";
$('#center').load(url);
```

When debugger his the breakpoint in my action on first line, iMode variable shows proper value of 7, strSearch parameter arrives as null.

Any help/advice would be most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the ampersand instead of `&amp;`

`url = "/MyController/MyAction?iMode=7&strSearch=as";`

Comment: Thank you. Working well now. This string was generated via MVC helper function @Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { iMode ="PLACEHOLDER", strSearch = "PLACEHOLDER1" })
I then did replacements of the placeholders, but assumed the &amp; to be an MVC quirk.

Comment: Haha yeah, there's quite a bit of quirks.. You should use the data object in jQuery ajax for sending data. It takes care of the name value pairs, encoding, _etc._

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Innatepirate for the tip. Wasted enough time trying to figure out why controller is getting null values. Replacing `&amp;` with ampersand did the trick. By the way I was doing the simple age old window.location.href = link and still had the problem. Probably its the MVC parsing and routing that is messing this up.